# Reading resources from an un-managed dll with C#

Tags: c#, dll, resources, unmanaged, unmanagedresources

I've written a command-line tool in C# which swaps out a resource in a .resources file for an alternative one. It uses ResourceReader and ResourceWriter.

I'd like to do the same thing for dll files, but I can't find a way of doing this. I tried using Reflection, but that only works on DLLs which are .net (managed) ones. Most of the dlls I'm using are built with other things.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this! Things like Resource Hacker do it, so it must be possible.

Can anyone help, please?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you would have to get specifications on how to interpret the binary content in the DLL. If you have plain old Windows DLLs you should check on MSDN.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this, but I was hoping to do it with C#. Do you know if there are C# equivalents of these functions? They all seem to have been replaced with the Reflection versions.

Answer (score 0):

A really good step-by-step guide can be found here: [How to load unmanaged (native) resources from managed C# code](http://khason.net/blog/how-to-load-unmanaged-native-resources-from-managed-c-code/)